# Trying to fix autohotkey code which do a function when I press a key twice

Tags: autohotkey

I want to write a code in aoutohotkey to do this: If the my dictionary application is active, then when I press the key " j " it clicks on a specific coordinate (in this coordinate there is an open Kmplayer window ) then send Enter  and then send Space. here is my code:

```
#IfWinActive Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary
j::
    If (A_ThisHotkey = A_PriorHotkey) && (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 500)
        Click, 1149,305
        sleep,100
        send,{Enter}
        sleep,100
        send,{space}
return
```

But it doesn't work perfectly. sometimes it works but most of the times when I press the key " j "  twice, it just send space and enter.

Some details:

1. I'm not much experienced at working with aoutohotkey I just found a double tap pressing code on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/abbc0t/how_do_a_press_a_key_twice_to_trigger_a_function/) and used it.
2. For swiping window to the open Kmplayer I didn't find a better solution than just `Click, 1149,305` because unlike many applications, the key combination Alt+Esc doesn't swap windows for Oxford dictionary app. (maybe this clicking cause the problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your if-statement's body has more than one line, you need `{ }`s.

```
#IfWinActive Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary
j::
    if (A_ThisHotkey = A_PriorHotkey && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 500)
    {
        Click, 1149,305
        sleep,100
        send,{Enter}
        sleep,100
        send,{space}
    }
return
```

Not sure if this is your only problem though.
I wasn't able to make sense of what your second detail was trying to say.

Comment: Thank you very much! that worked ! but there is a problem. when I press " j " one time, it doesn't type the letter " j ". how can I fix that? I think to do that maybe I should add ```else {....}``` at the end but couldn't figure out how.

Comment: I just added   ```else    send,{j}``` at the end and it is ok now!

Comment: Remove the `{ }` from the send command. They don't belong there.

Comment: Oops! Yeah it is a typo